# labels does not print the entire string

Tags: c#, winforms

I have dynamically created an array of labels. however, when i tried to set label.text = "hahaha hehehehe hmmmm", it displays only "hahaha" and not anything after the space.

```
for (int i = 0; i < labelArray.Length; i++)
{
    labelArray[i] = new Label();
    labelArray[i].BackColor = Color.Bisque;
    labelArray[i].Font = new Font(labelArray[i].Font.FontFamily, labelArray[i].Font.Size + 5, FontStyle.Bold);
    labelArray[i].Location = new Point(25, temp);
    labelArray[i].Name = "searchLabel" + i.ToString();
    labelArray[i].Text = "hahahahaha";
    labelArray[i].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(main_MouseEnter);
    labelArray[i].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(main_MouseLeave);
    searchPanel.Controls.Add(labelArray[i]);
    temp += 40; ;
}
```

have I missed out any anything? btw, this is the "initialization" done in Form_load and I edited the label.text in a TextChanged event. many thanks!

edit: I have since fixed the problem by setting autosize to true.

I have tried to display e.g. "hahahahahahahahaha hmmmmmm hehehehehehehehhe" and "ha hmmmmmmm hehehehehehhe" and in both cases only the first word gets displayed so I dont think it is being truncated..

the code which i used to set the text is simply:

> labelArray[11].Text = "hahahahahahahahahaha eheheheheh hmmmmm";

Comment: That means, after `hahahaha`, you cannot do `hehehe`. Its not good for health :P

Comment: Can you post the code that adds the rest of the text?

Comment: Are you sure that it's cutting at the space? Have you tried setting the text to "ha ha" to see what happens? And are we talking about how it displays, or viewing the text in the debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting [`AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize.aspx) attribute to `true`

```
labelArray[i].AutoSize = true;
```

Comment: oh yes the autosize works! thank you thank you! shall go read the api for it right onw!